# Memory utilization in Centos OS 6.6 (Virtual and RSS)

Tags: centos, virtualization, memory, memory-usage, multi-threading

My C++11 application run for days without reboot to perform fluid simulation.
After running it for 6days, this is the memory footprint:
RSS 54MB VSZ 5.6GB
Why virtual memory increased to 5.6GB? There is no memory leak in my application. Application is multi-threaded, and heavily uses STL.

Comment: Do you want to have VSZ and RSS explained? If so, I expect [Does it make sense to use VSZ from the ps command to monitor memory of processes on a Redhat server?](https://serverfault.com/q/825611/126632) will answer your question. The fact that your program is only using 54MB of RAM does not seem to be a significant concern.

Comment: @Michael thanks for your comment. I partially got my answer. I am still did not get it why Centos is keeping of already used memory information in VSZ.

Comment: Could there be an allocation leak where you forgot to unlink or unmap? Maybe monitor the VSZ increase and check with lsof? You can also check `/proc/<pid>/smaps`

Comment: I checked /proc/<pid>/smaps but did not find any leaks. Also, if there is any memory leak than RSS size should also grow. But RSS size remains same.